# Why is this argument not working?

Tags: javascript, sankey-diagram

I am trying to generate values dynamically and pass that to a function.

This is my code,

```
var color="{\"Hello\":\"#276040\"}";
alert(color); \\displays {"Hello":"#276040"}
sankey.setColors(color);
```

When I pass the color variable into that function it fails.

Instead of passing the argument, if I give the string directly it works.

```
sankey.setColors({"Hello":"#276040"}); //This works
```

What is the reason? How can I overcome that?

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: A string representation of an object is a string, not an object. You're mixing things up. If `setColors` expects an object, then you need to pass an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it as object. string is not a valid data for that

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the dynamic parts of your parameters are the key name and value, you could do something like:

```
var keyName = 'Hello';
var keyValue = '#276040';
sankey.setColors( { keyName: keyValue} );
```

Answer (score 2):

var color contains a string in your code, Be careful for what sankey.setColors need. 
"{\"Hello\":\"#276040\"}" and {"Hello":"#276040"} isn't same values.